# Devise's losing current_account

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, devise

I did sign_in, then go to '/edit' and i see my email. Than reload page and i redirected to sign_in again! Why did devise lose my session?

Comment: sorry dude i am newb. is everyth clear?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This here: http://weblog.rubyonrails.org/2011/2/8/csrf-protection-bypass-in-ruby-on-rails
is most likely the cause of your problem. I had the same problem and using that as a starting point helped me fix the issue. unfortunately I do not recall the exact steps I took.